# JAXB Unmarshall is removing carriage return in digital signature

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, marshalling, digital-signature, unmarshalling

I'm doing XML signature using the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I'm able to successfully generate the signature using an envelope:

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><DigestValue>xndyhbkzbLreG3cxXqa5Q5RdKEavhrc2Fvd0Wsc+Oug=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>No+gNx3Hwd3WfH0v6OZ8uptWVyneZT55CfUrxMnW33a87egeiImwsyepZZXTbya0ifzX1iOtyyaf&#13;
OwEDxTFhf/FCPH6Nj9KCFNabZddwN38tCOkkAkYdkKdW14AM80HU/9yPIAMWytibbyd3AKVuRQgd&#13;
+qkf1/V8J1Ki1LNO4tbPzxqpNMpRmpH/469lgMHEz9Xy1DnJ154E+H2OWNufooGwwpV/pMbM8RzY&#13;
```

When I try to validate like this, it works:

```
 signature.sign(dsc);

 System.out.println("doc: " + getStringFromDocument(doc) + " validate: " + validate(doc));
```

However, it fails when I try to unmarshal the signature so that I can assign it to a DTO:

```
JAXBElement<?> root = XmlUtils.getUnMarshaller(xml.getClass().getName()).unmarshal(getStreamSource(doc), xml.getClass());

xml.setSignature(((SignXml<?>) root.getValue()).getSignature());
```

When comparing the signature generated in the doc and the one being unmarshalled, I found out that the character 
 is removed:

doc

```
<SignatureValue>No+gNx3Hwd3WfH0v6OZ8uptWVyneZT55CfUrxMnW33a87egeiImwsyepZZXTbya0ifzX1iOtyyaf&#13;
    OwEDxTFhf/FCPH6Nj9KCFNabZddwN38tCOkkAkYdkKdW14AM80HU/9yPIAMWytibbyd3AKVuRQgd&#13;
    +qkf1/V8J1Ki1LNO4tbPzxqpNMpRmpH/469lgMHEz9Xy1DnJ154E+H2OWNufooGwwpV/pMbM8RzY&#13;
    +yVSjKguJr9UWKWswQkD0XUasVXBZckjlYxZL24ZwD1rwU7wP2itOli3VH9ReC3CA33YOUMT0ktP&#13;
```

unmarshall

```
<ns2:SignatureValue>No+gNx3Hwd3WfH0v6OZ8uptWVyneZT55CfUrxMnW33a87egeiImwsyepZZXTbya0ifzX1iOtyyafOwEDxTFhf/FCPH6Nj9KCFNabZddwN38tCOkkAkYdkKdW14AM80HU/9yPIAMWyt
```

As we can see, the signature are the same with the only difference of character &#13 being removed.

I tried looking at the EscapeCharacter solution but it seems like it's only available in older JAXB implementations. Any idea?